# DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS returns trigger does not exist

Tags: php, mysql

Not sure what's wrong here. I've a database and a query statement to remove the trigger if it exists. There are currently no trigger created with name = `table_name_after_insert` or `table_name_before_insert`.

> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS table_name_after_insert;

The above query returns an error `Trigger does not exist` even after the usage of `IF EXISTS` in the query.

If I try to drop the `before_insert`, trigger, there is no error returned by the query -

```
mysql> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS table_name_after_insert;
ERROR 1360 (HY000): Trigger does not exist
mysql> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS table_name_before_insert;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
mysql> SHOW WARNINGS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  Level: Note
   Code: 1360
Message: Trigger does not exist
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Can anyone pls explain why the first query is resulting in an error?

The docs at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/drop-trigger.html don't seem to provide any other possibilities of dropping a trigger from the table. There might be something inside mysql files or backup directories that is messing up with this DROP query?

UPDATE -

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS WHERE EVENT_OBJECT_SCHEMA='db_name' AND EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE='table_name';
Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: 1) Show `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS WHERE EVENT_OBJECT_SCHEMA='your database' AND EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE='your table'\G<Enter>`. 2) Show warning after 2nd query execution.

Comment: Have updated the post with the query output

Comment: Well, none triggers exists on this table - even in another schemes available for you. But what about the warning after 2nd query?

Comment: updated. I see the warning is same as the error I get in the first query. So why does it error in the first one and show only warning on the second?